# How to send data with delay vue js?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

every time when i use input , my function send data to server and i get response, but if i want to write in field 'name' - Thomas Edison , i will send letter by letter

i try to put setTimeout function and if user still writing a string nothing will be send , but i does not work

```html
 @input="throttledSave"
```

```
  throttledSave (e) {
                let eva = e 
                let DELAY = 2000;
                if(e.target.value){
                    return this.throttle(this.setDataFinalJSON, DELAY, eva);
                }
            },

     throttle: function (callback, limit,eva) {
            var wait = false;
            var typingTimer;
            return function (callback, limit,eva) {
                clearTimeout(typingTimer)
                if (!wait) {
                    callback(eva);
                    wait = true;
                    typingTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                        console.log('oh again')
                        wait = false;
                    }, limit);
                }
            }
        }
```

every time it is work  until DELAY , i don't know why, maybe clearTimeout does not work , i got stuck. I don't know why if i write some text so fast i got console.log('oh again')

Answer (score 4):

You could do this with lodash debounce (https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce) method:

> Creates a debounced function that delays invoking func until after
>   wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time the debounced
>   function was invoked. The debounced function comes with a cancel
>   method to cancel delayed func invocations and a flush method to
>   immediately invoke them. Provide options to indicate whether func
>   should be invoked on the leading and/or trailing edge of the wait
>   timeout. The func is invoked with the last arguments provided to the
>   debounced function. Subsequent calls to the debounced function return
>   the result of the last func invocation.

```
_.debounce(func, [wait=0], [options={}])
```

Example:

```
methods: {
    throttledMethod: _.debounce(() => {
      console.log('I only get fired once every two seconds, max!')
    }, 2000)
  }
```

Best to use the vue variant of lodash: https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-lodash

Answer (score 3):

Timeout just delays each input event (so that each one causes the request, just after some time) which is not what you want. The basic idea of implementing this is simple: store the time of the last input event in the model, and on input, send your requests only when timeout has passed, something like:

```
data () {
    return {
        ...
        lastInputTime: null,
        inputTimeout: 1000 // ms
    }
},
...
methods: {
    throttledSave (e) {
        const attemptTime = new Date();
        if(this.lastInputTime && attemptTime - this.lastInputTime > this.inputTimeout) {
            // get value, send request etc
        }
        this.lastInputTime = attemptTime;
    }
```

Well, this is exactly what is called debounce, dreijntjens suggests a similar thing but using a library which allows to decorate your function.

PS Actually, such decorating is a better approach (unless you are planning to change `inputTimeout` in runtime) since you don't clutter your model with extra stuff specific to debouncing; you can make your own "decorator" (not in the strict sence, decorators are supposed to have [special syntax](https://github.com/wycats/javascript-decorators), rather than being a function that gets your function and returns a modified one) if your project doesn't tree-shake libraries properly. Something like this:

```
function debounce(func, timeout) {
    let lastTime = null;
    return function() {
        const attemptTime = new Date();
        if(lastTime && attemptTime - lastTime > timeout) {
            func.apply(this, arguments);
        }
        lastTime = attemptTime;
    }
}
```

lodash's implementation is much more [sophisticated](https://github.com/lodash/lodash/blob/4.17.15/lodash.js#L10304) since it supports several [options](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce).

Comment: not really want i want to do , but look it's work perfectly here http://jsfiddle.net/ZYXp4/8/ just exactly what i want , but i don't know , why i have different  output in my code

Comment: @Bravis well, in that snippet you are updating DOM which is a sync operation, so it may perform differently, but it's a good question why exactly that one works like you want

Answer (score 1):

How about using the lazy input model modifier?

[VueJS prototype for delayed (lazy) input](https://gist.github.com/a-vision/d5f179fb03d4883f0775f4182f7fb7f5)

```
Vue.prototype.lazyInput = function(e, delay) {
    const self = this;
    if (typeof delay == 'undefined') {
        delay = 500;
    }
    const target = e.target;
    if (self.lazyTimer) {
        clearTimeout(self.lazyTimer);
        self.lazyTimer = null;
    }
    self.lazyTimer = setTimeout(function(){
        target.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
    }, delay);
}
```

Usage:

```
<input v-model.lazy="{variableName}" @input="lazyInput($event)">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the native setTimeout()

```
methods: {
   search: function (event) {
       clearTimeout(this.timeout)
       this.timeout = setTimeout(() => {
          ... XMLHttpRequest ... 
       }, 2000)
```

every 2000 msec sending request if no new data.